# PowerShell 7.2 Get-Service Not Working on Remote Server

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get to a Windows service on a remote server and I am using the following command-

```
Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName -Name $ServiceName
```

Running this throws the following exception-

> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComputerName'.

I am using PowerShell 7.2.

Thank you,
Bill

Comment: Did you read the help? In version 7 `Get-Service` does not offer remoting. You will have to use `Invoke-Command` or `Get-CimInstance` to get the services on a remote computer.

Comment: Thanks Olaf - what's curious is that when I did a search on PowerShell 7.2 Connect to Remote Server the top results all said to use Get-Service hence my confusion.

Comment: So either you got it wrong or they. You may contact them and tell them. ;-)